# get immediate child node of a parant node of an xml file using powershell

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, powershell

I have an xml file like given below

```
 <ParentNode>
   <childnode1>
    <Name string="Code1"/>
   </childnode1>

   <childnode2>
    <Name string="Code2"/>
   </childnode2>
   <childnode3>
    <Name string="Code3"/>
   </childnode3>
</ParentNode>
```

how can i print all the child nodes of ParentNode using powershell

i tried by using given code

```
foreach($child in $xmlfile.ParentNode)
{
Write-Host $child
}
```

it should print

```
childnode1
childnode2
childnode3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
PS>[xml]$x=gc c:\temp\xml.xml    
PS>$x.ParentNode
```

or maybe you want :

```
PS>$x.ParentNode |gm -MemberType property |select -expand name     
childnode1                                                         
childnode2                                                         
childnode3
```